# How to Prevent iOS Screen Capture Programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, screen, screenshot

I have developed an iOS which contains some confidential information in videos and pics. I want to protect them from screen capturing. Is there any way to provide security for them? I would like to prevent my app from screen recording apps like iRec. Please provide me some solutions.

Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this using *NSNotificationCenter* to add an observer to *UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification*.

```
NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
                                              object:nil
                                               queue:mainQueue
                                          usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                             // executes after screenshot
                                          }];
```

Comment: Thanks @Paddy.. Its working fine while taking screenshots. But it is not working for screen capturing/ Recording. Please provide me some details if you have any.